# Question marks in email for characters like non-breaking space. It only occurs on Unix and not on Windows

Tags: unix, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I am facing a weird problem related to content type/encoding.
Here is my Java code snippet below. This code works perfectly fine on a Windows machine where the application server is running on windows and the [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) server for sending emails is also Windows localhost. When I deploy the same code on a Unix server, the email sent for the exact same content contains question marks (???) for special characters like non-breaking white space.

I did a lot of googling, but I did not find any solution. How can I fix this problem? The content types I tried were [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Nothing helps.

```
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                .............

        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart messageBody = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBody.setContent(mailMessage, "text/html;charset=Windows-1252");
        messageBody.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=Windows-1252");

        // Add body to the multimedia part
        mp.addBodyPart(messageBody);
        message.setContent(mp);

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: Do the generated messages differ, and/or are you using a different mail client to view the messages? My guess is that your Unix MUA lacks the support for UTF8, or you are running it with the wrong locale settings.

Comment: @tripleee, i am using the same mail client that is microsoft outlook that is on my laptop to receive these emails. The generated message is also the same in content.

Comment: I mean if you diff the messages (their "source" in modern-day email parlance) how do they differ? If Outlook renders them differently there must be significant differences, most probably in the Content-* headers.

Comment: @tripleee, the difference is that, i get ?? for those characters when i see the html source of the email i get. So, it will not matter what the content type is sent as meta header in html, question marks will always be question marks. It is something on the unix side that is making those special characters (non breaking space) to send as question marks over email message content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, I had to go with a crude way of doing it. I replaced such characters with space.

```
mailMessage.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", " ");
```

Now, all the special characters like non-breaking space or any other character falling out of normal range, will be replaced with space. The email in this case was anyway meant for normal text.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the same mail server in both cases?  And the same client program to view the message?

For debugging, just before the Transport.send call, add:

```
message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt"));
```

and then examine the msg.txt file to see if the characters are correctly encoded.

How do you create the text in the mailMessage String?  If you don't create the string with the correct Unicode characters, no charset is going to make it right.

Also, you don't ever need to set the Content-Type header explicitly, remove that line.

And, instead of setContent, use:

```
messageBody.setText(mailMessage, "html", "utf-8");
```

That makes sure the Content-Type header is set correctly and the parameters (e.g., charset) are quoted correctly.

Comment: i wrote the txt file as you suggested. It also has the question marks (???) and this is what it has:  <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
I tried your setText method. It doesn't resolve the problem either. The message does have the correct characters as the same setup/code works on windows (when everything is on windows)

Comment: please ignore the html code i pasted above. That is part of the message and hardcoded the content type there.

Comment: So does the email's Content-Type header disagree with the HTTP-Equivs header in the HTML payload?

Comment: If you're getting question marks in the msg.txt file, something more basic is wrong.  It suggests that the question marks are in the original string.  What non-ASCII data do you have in the original string and how did you construct the original string?  If you write just the original string to a file, what do you get?

Comment: the characters are coming from the data in my database. And the data looks good. The characters are actually non-breaking space (that is what they call it). if i open that string in notepad on my machine, it shows properly.

Comment: So are you getting unclean text from your database connection? Where is the database running and how are you attaching to it?

Comment: The data in the database may be using the default charset for your operating system (instead of utf-8) and may not be being properly converted to Unicode characters when constructing a Java String object from the characters in the database.  That's why, when you write the string out to a file, you can view it in Notepad; Notepad is using the default charset.  Look at the integer value of each character in your Java String to make sure they're the expected Unicode characters, in particular for the non-breaking space character.

Comment: Thanks @BillShannon you have saved my lot of time. string.setText worked for me